# Django - inlineformset-factory (How to Edit)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, inline-formset

I saw many tutorials and questions in many foruns and websites. And when I search for "inline formset-factory" are many links appear. But  few talk about how edit, with inline formset-factory.
I have a problem in my project, I did it save, but when I will try edit, rise some errors

This is my code

```
class Dia_Producao(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    diaTrabalho = models.CharField("Dia de Trabalho", choices=DIATRABALHO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=False, max_length=10)
    dataTrabalho = models.DateField("Data de Trabalho")
    fkSemanaMes = models.ForeignKey(Semana_Mes, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Semana do Mês")
    dataCadastro = models.DateTimeField("Data Cadastro", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    statusBaixa = models.BooleanField("Status Baixa")

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" %(str(self.diaTrabalho), self.fkSemanaMes)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        view_name = "dias_trabalho"
        return reverse(view_name)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Dia Produções"

class Digi_Usu(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fkDiaProducao = models.ForeignKey(Dia_Producao, verbose_name="Dia Produção")
    fkUsuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Usuário")
    totalDia = models.IntegerField("Total do Dia")



    def __str__(self):
        return "%s / %s" %(self.fkDiaProducao, self.fkUsuario)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.fkDiaProducao)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Dia Semana"

class Hora(models.Model):
    hora = models.CharField("Hora Trabalho", choices=HORA_CHOICES, blank=True, null=False,max_length=6)
    qtdlHora = models.IntegerField("Total Hora")
    dataCadastro = models.DateTimeField("Data Cadastro", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    fkDigiUsu = models.ForeignKey(Digi_Usu, verbose_name="Dia Producao/Usuário")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hora

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hora
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Horas"
```

in my form.py.

```
HoraFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Digi_Usu,  Hora, fields='__all__', extra=0, max_num=24)
```

views.py

```
class DigitalizacaoCreateView(CreateView):

    model = Digi_Usu, Hora, Dia_Producao,Usuario
    template_name = 'producao/digitalizacao/digitalizacao_create.html'
    form_class = DigitalizacaoModelForm

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DigitalizacaoCreateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["title"]= "Lançar Digitalização"
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object  = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        hora_form = HoraFormSet()
        return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(form=form, hora_form=hora_form)
            )

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

            self.object = None
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form = self.get_form(form_class)
            hora_form = HoraFormSet(self.request.POST)
            if (form.is_valid() and hora_form.is_valid()):
                return self.form_valid(form, hora_form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form, hora_form)

            return
        def form_valid(self, form, hora_form):
            self.object = form.save()
            hora_form.instance = self.object
            hora_form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_sucess_url())

        def form_invalid(self, form, hora_form):
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                                                 hora_form=hora_form))

        def get_sucess_url(self):
            return reverse("digi")

        def get_queryset(self):
            qs = Digi_Usu.objects.all()
            # qs = Hora.objects.filter(fkDigiUsu__fkUsuario__usuario__exact="USUARIO 1", fkDigiUsu__fkDiaProducao__diaTrabalho="01").aggregate(total_itens=Sum('qtdlHora'))
            return qs

class DigitalizacaoUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'producao/digitalizacao/digitalizacao_update.html'
    form_class = DigitalizacaoModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("digi")

    def get_queryset(self):
        #pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        qs = Digi_Usu.objects.all()
        return qs

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object  = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        hora_form = HoraFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(
            form=form,
            hora_form=hora_form)
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        hora_form = HoraFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if (form.is_valid() and hora_form.is_valid()):
            return self.form_valid(form, hora_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, hora_form)

        return

    def form_valid(self, form, hora_form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        print(self.object)
        hora_form.instance = self.object
        print(hora_form.instance)
        hora_form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_sucess_url())


    def form_invalid(self, form, hora_form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                                             hora_form=hora_form))
```

template:

```
<div>
    <div class="entry">
        <form role="form" action="" method="post">

            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12  ">
                {{ form|crispy}}
            </div>

            <fieldset>
               <legend>Lançar Horas</legend>
               {{ hora_form.management_form }}
               {{ hora_form.non_form_errors }}
               {% for form in hora_form %}
                   {{ form.id }}
                   <div class="inline {{ hora_form.prefix }}">
                       {{ form.hora.errors }}
                       {{ form.hora.label_tag }}
                       {{ form.hora }}
                       {{ form.qtdlHora.errors }}
                       {{ form.qtdlHora.label_tag }}
                       {{ form.qtdlHora }}
                   </div>
               {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>

            <script type="text/html" id="book-template">
                <div id="hora-__prefix__">
                    {{ hora_form.empty_form }}
                </div>
            </script>
            </div>  <!-- this closing tag ? -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 h2"> <p><a href="{% url 'digi' %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-md" role="button" ><i class=""></i> Voltar</a> </p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 h2"> <input class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-md" type="submit" value="Salvar" /> </div>
            </div>

         </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

error

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/control/producao/digitalizacao/update/16/

Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'djangoformsetjs',
 'dash']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/src/dash/views.py" in post
  204.             return self.form_valid(form, hora_form)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/src/dash/views.py" in form_valid
  215.         hora_form.save()

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  646.         return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_existing_objects
  765.                 saved_instances.append(self.save_existing(form, obj, commit=commit))

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_existing
  628.         return form.save(commit=commit)

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  448.             self.instance.save()

File "/home/douglasm/Documentos/sources/controlsys/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  752.                         "unsaved related object '%s'." % field.name

Exception Type: ValueError at /control/producao/digitalizacao/update/16/
Exception Value: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'fkDigiUsu'.
```

Comment: I suggest you to remove the `commit=False` from `self.object = form.save(commit=False)`. Generally that flag is set to False when you need to perform some actions before django perform an insert in the database. Since you don't seem to need that, you can just save the form (i.e. just `self.object = form.save()`).